# Error "could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'" showing when trying to clone a github repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-clone

When I tried to clone a Github repository I encountered the following error:

> could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'

Please help how I can resolve this error. I tried looking for it but there are hardly any solutions or articles online.

Comment: Can you show us the complete output of the clone operation as a code block (by editing it into your question)?  What operating system are you using?  Is this on GitHub Actions or on your local machine?  Is there anything else interesting going on (e.g., WSL, a non-default antivirus, a remote file system or cloud syncing service)?